# boto3 connects from EC2 instance to secrets manager but unable to connect from inside docker container after IMDSv2 required upgrade

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

boto3 connects from EC2 instance with the following command returns a result.

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(service_name = 'secretmanager', region_name = 'us-east-1')
get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(secretId = secret_name)
```

However, when I run the same set of commands from inside a docker container deployed on the EC2 instance it fails with the No credentials error. EC2 instance has an IAM role attached to be able to fetch passwords from secrets manager.

Comment: Does running `aws sts get-caller-identity` on the ec2 instance show the correct role?

Comment: It does. @jordan

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that you're using IMDSv2, which is likely the issue. Unfortunately I don't have an answer as i've never done this with v2, but I'm guessing it will involve passing the IMDS token to the docker container on start.

Comment: That's precisely the problem, @Jordanm
We tried by making the EC2 instance metadata back to IMDSv1 and it works. Unfortunately, the CICD team decides its time to move to IMDSv2 so here we are. Thanks for trying to help. Let me know if you see a page or a document about this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to [increase the hop limit](https://engineering.instawork.com/a-tale-of-performance-ecs-boto3-iam-dd22a2624398).

> What are hops, and why are they significant?
>
> To ensure IP packets have a limited lifetime on the network, all IP
> packets have an 8 bit Time to Live (IPv4) or Hop Limit (IPv6) header
> field and value which specifies the maximum number of layer three hops
> (typically routers) that can be traversed on the path to their
> destination.
>
> Each time the packet arrives at a layer three network device (a Hop),
> the value is reduced by one before it gets routed onward. When the
> value eventually reaches one, the packet gets discarded by the device
> that receives it (as the value would get reduced to zero).
>
> So the docker networking layer will just drop the response from IMDSv2
> calls!
>
> We now increase the hop count using the following command.

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options  --instance-id i-XXXXXXXXXXXX --http-put-response-hop-limit 3
```

[This AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html) says:

> By default, the response to PUT requests has a response hop limit
> (time to live) of 1 at the IP protocol level. You can adjust the hop
> limit using the modify-instance-metadata-options command if you need
> to make it larger. **For example, you might need a larger hop limit for
> backward compatibility with container services running on the
> instance.** For more information, see modify-instance-metadata-options
> in the AWS CLI Command Reference.

Also related: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-eks-supports-ec2-instance-metadata-service-v2/

Comment: Wow. such a unique solution. This worked. Thanks Shawn. I recreated the instance with the updated instance meta data, deployed a container and after this change am able to fetch the password from secrets manager through boto3. Thanks again.